# selecting date range and setting default date according to on change select element in moodle form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, moodle, moodle-api

I am new in moodl plugins. I am looking to select date range and setting the default date in moodle form which will depend on selection value of a drop down value. 
it will be really great if anyone can help me.

I have tried this code but does not solve the problem.

```
function init() {

    $('#id_term').change(function() {

       $('#id_from').load=('dropdownvalpicker.php');        
    });
}
```

dropdownvaluepicker.php  file:

```
 $year=2019; $month=9;$day=1;// then make timestamp of your date
 $defaulttime = make_timestamp($year, $month, $day);
// echo $mform->addElement('date_selector', 'from', get_string('from'));
//  echo "$mform->setDefault('from',  $defaulttime)"; 
 echo $defaulttime;


    //code in the form.php file 

$mform->addElement('date_selector', 'from', get_string('from'),$yearrange);
         $mform->setType('from',PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Hey! It would help others if you told us what is wrong: Show the error messages if there are errors or display the result. What are the drop down values and their dependency looking like? Maybe add some screenshots showing the problem.

Comment: hi, it just print the timestamp.if i use only third echo in the body but does not display date picker.

Comment: I think you are mixing things here (but i'm not a moodle expert. Try this: `$mform->setDefault('from',  $defaulttime); 
 echo $mform->addElement('date_selector', 'from', get_string('from'));` You don't want to send the default date to the browser but to run it on the server and pass only the selector with a set default time to the browser.

Comment: Hi Pauloco, Thanks for your reply. No it does not. It will work only from the form.php file without using any java script. but I would like to make default time dynamic. Hence, I need to use jquery/java script also.

Comment: Ok, just to understand: where do you call the form.php? Right now your are calling directly the dropdownvaluepicker.php. Which will echo stuff into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mform->setDefault('date_field', date('U', strtotime("+14 days")));
```

The following code changes the default value of the date picker from today’s date to 14 days in the future. The second parameter returns the date in `Unix` format 14 days from now.